# UTF-8 comment highlighting in lstlisting

Tags: lstlisting, listingsutf8

I am writing a document full of UTF-8 characters and code, so I am using CJKutf8 package with lstlisting. However, it seems that there is something wrong with text highlighting.

In the example below, it seems that only ASCII characters are colored blue, but not the UTF-8 characters (Chinese and Japanese). Why is this happening? Is there an esay fix to this problem?

Result:

[image: result]

Source:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tikz}

\lstset{
  extendedchars=false,
  commentstyle=\color{blue},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}

Text % may contain UTF-8 characters

\begin{lstlisting} [language=Python]
# Comment
# 注释 comment
# コメント comment
\end{lstlisting}

Text % may contain UTF-8 characters

\newpage
\end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think that there is an easy fix. listings handles the input token by token, and as you a telling it with extendedchars=false to let cjk alone it doesn't handle it. You probly will have to escape to latex and use escapebegin to set the color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually simpler than expected: `listings` has a `texcl` option causing "the comment line text (up to the end of line) is read as LaTeX code and typeset in comment style" (manual page 40). This means that the comments are processed by CJKutf8, which allows text to be colored.

To preserve spaces you can use the `\obeyspaces` command as argument to the `escapebegin` key from `listings`. Unfortunately this does not work for tabs.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tikz}

\lstset{
  extendedchars=false,
  commentstyle=\color{blue},
  texcl,
  escapebegin=\obeyspaces
}

\begin{document}
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}

Text % may contain UTF-8 characters

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python]
# Comment
# 注释 comment      with spaces       and tabs
# コメント comment
\end{lstlisting}

Text % may contain UTF-8 characters

\newpage
\end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: It solves what I need, but with one flaw: if the comment has more than 1 space (e.g. some `Tab`s), they get collapsed into one space.

Comment: @EricStdlib for spaces there is a solution (see edit), for tabs I didn't find anything unfortunately.